# Use a WebBrowser on a Script Task of SSIS

Tags: browser, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

Hi I'm in need to download a file from a site that requires Forms Auth (through SSL) on a **SSIS** (*SQL Server Integration Services 2008 R2*) **Script Task**.

I'm currently using VB.NET with COM CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application"), C# code is helping me also.

I've a few doubts,

1. Is there a better wrapper library for webbrowser like using *SELENIUM* or *WATIN*?
2. How do I perform a download with this browser control?

Any help is appreciated,

Gabriel Guimarães

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Watin](http://watin.org/). It has a very complete API and great documentation

Comment: That looks amazing. I'd never heard of that before, but it opens up the possibility of automating a *ton* more of our administrative tasks.

Comment: Hi @santiiiii I'm aware of WATIN but is it ok to use on anything that is not a test?

Comment: Sure it is. I've used it myself to automate the daily downloading of files.

Comment: Can I download the dll only? is it a signed dll? can I sign it if its not? (SSIS only allows signed libraries)

Comment: There are dll files in the bin directory for several versions of the .NET Framework. As for signing, I'm not sure about that, but you can always sign it from Visual Studio